# Export SQL Server table to Microsoft Excel xlsx file

Tags: sql-server, excel, vb6

I have to replace a VB6 function that allows to export a SQL Server table in a xls file using DAO.

In order to use Excel 2007-2010... files (xlsx), I tried to use this function to do that but it doesn't work.

Here is the DAO functionnality :

```
//Opening the SQLServer database with DAO
Set oBase= DBEngine.OpenDatabase(DSNName, dbDriverNoPrompt, False, "ODBC,PROVIDER=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.3.51;DSN=DSNName;UID=user;PWD=pwd;DATABASE=SQLServerBDDName;Server=SQLServerName;")

//Query to export data
oBase.Execute("SELECT * INTO [SheetName] IN 'xlsFileName' 'Microsoft Excel 8.0;' FROM [SQLServerTableName]")
```

This function works perfectly with 97-2003 Excel files in xls but not with xlsx files.

Is there a possibility to make the same thing with ADO but without OPENROWSET statements or stored procedures ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: If I change Excel 8.0 by Excel 12.0 and the provider (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0), I have an error (ISAM drivers not found). I already installed Access driver 12 for another software

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/247412 gives a lot of different ways to do what you want.  However, DAO isn't one of them.  DAO was old in 1995, when ADO came out.  You may need to change to ADO to support Excel 12.0.  If so, it's not too difficult, and there's an example in the link.  For ADO connection strings, visit www.connectionstrings.com .

Comment: thanks for that but with our old method we could export data from sql server to a xls file without Office installed, only with Jet driver. All methods explained in this web page need Excel to work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to make in VB6 SQL Server export to Excel 2007 file with ADO and **WITHOUT** Office installed.

First, I use ADO to create xlsx file :

```
Dim l_oBase     As New ADODB.connection

l_oBase.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myExcelFile.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml"""
Call l_oBase.Open
```

Then I execute a query to export a table in a sheet by using ODBC connection and DSN to connect to SQL Server database :

```
l_sReq = "SELECT * INTO [mySheet] FROM [ODBC;DSN=MyDSN;UID=LoginSQL;PWD=pwdSQL;Server=MySQLServer;Database=myDatabase].[TableName];"
Call l_oBase.Execute(l_sReq)
Call l_oBase.Close
```

When I execute the query in debug mode, I obtain an error on execute but xlsx file is correctly created and populated with data formats.